# PHP - Sending email from form with mail function

Tags: php, email

I have been looking at this for hours now, and I can't figure out why this won't work. I'm trying to send an email using the mail function. For some reason this page works when hosted by iPage, but not by Godaddy. What is the reason for this?

The PHP:

```
<?php
// Run code if button pressed
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// Makes sure all fields are filled
if (!$_POST['name'] | !$_POST['email'] | !$_POST['message'] ) {
  ?><script>alert('You forgot to fill in a field');window.location = "http://example.com/contact.php";</script>
  <?php
  exit;
  }

// From the form
  $name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
  $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
  $message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

  $to = 'email@gmail.com';
  $subject = "Contact form submitted!";

  $body = <<<HTML
$message
HTML;

       $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
       $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

       // send the email
       mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
     ?><script>alert('Thanks! I will try to get back to you as soon as possible.');window.location = "http://example.com/contact.php";</script><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all, WHAT isn't working? For starters, enable error reporting in php so you can rule out things like syntax errors.

Comment: I'm not receiving an email. But only on one host...

Comment: What kind of email box are you sending to? If you're sending to a Gmail box, for example, the server you're sending from might be blacklisted already (and you might bet a bounce-back message eventually in the sender's box). I've experienced this often on shared hosting, and even some higher-quality servers. This is one of the reasons many have chosen to switch to a mail sending platform (mailgun, sendgrid, mailchimp, etc). Unfortunately, SPAMmers can ruin hosting for the rest of us.

Comment: Have you asked about email service in your GoDaddy account whether available or not? try sending email without form first. What error you get in mail log?

Comment: Check to see if you have php mailer pear package installed

Comment: After a long talk with go daddy customer support, they told me to try a different form mailer.

Comment: If it's working on one host and not another, why are you blaming the code and not the host?

Comment: It still doesn't work, even with the `||`. It defiantly isn't a syntax error, because it works on one of the hosts. It has something to do with go daddy, I just don't know what. Also, can anyone elaborate as to why this is a bad question? It received 2 down votes.

Comment: From experience, GoDaddy will lie to you all day. They also have bizarre hosting configurations. It's quite possible they have the mail command disabled. The mail() command uses the system's local mailer, sendmail I think. Is it Windows or Linux hosting? I'm thinking this is more of an incompetent host issue than a programming one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people having trouble sending email on GoDaddy's servers, here's whats going on:

To prevent spam, GoDaddy's servers refuse to send your mail if your using a certain domain (see below for the list). So to solve the specific problem here, I had to change the domain I was using, so `$to = 'email@gmail';` is now `$to = 'email@something-else.com';`

Here is GoDaddy's [explanation](http://support.godaddy.com/godaddy/having-problems-with-your-websites-form-mailer/) and the list of blacklisted domains:

> Forms are popular on websites; they let customers share their information with you, whether it’s for a newsletter or to register an account. Often times, these forms email a confirmation of the visitor’s submission to to you or the visitor submitting the information. Did you know that all email, even if it’s sent from a hosting account, must have information entered in the From value, though?
>
> You can make that From value a particular email address, too. This lets you create a professional-looking email for your customers or something that’s easy to categorize for yourself.
>
> However, we have to be careful with what users can specify as their From value to combat spamming attempts. Here’s a list of email address domain names we don’t let our customers use as the From value of their forms:

- gmail.com
- aol.com
- aim.com
- yahoo.com
- hotmail.com
- live.com
- msn.com

> If your email form uses one of these domain names for its From email address, our server will not send the email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your `if condition` you need `||` to do a `OR`

```
<?php
// Run code if button pressed
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// Makes sure all fields are filled
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message']) ) { 

?>
<script>alert('You forgot to fill in a field');
window.location = "http://example.com/contact.php";
</script>

<?php

exit;
}
```

**You are setting `From` email id `$email` from user Input, that means its not configured at your server, add a `Reply-To` header to $email**

```
$headers = "From: youremail@yourdomain.com \r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email. "\r\n" .
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
```

Final note, I would suggest you to use `Swift Mailer` or `PHP Mailer` to make it simple